# Angular 6, Obtain a new object from objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Lists I have

```
defaultUsers: any[] = [
  {id: 31, name: "A"},
  {id: 32, name: "B"},
  {id: 33, name: "C"},
  {id: 34, name: "D"},
  {id: 35, name: "E"},
  {id: 36, name: "F"},
  {id: 37, name: "G"},
  {id: 38, name: "H"},
];

onlineUsers: any[]= [
  {userid: 31, platform: 'web'},
  {userid: 31, platform: 'mobil'},
  {userid: 32, platform: 'mobil'},
];

users: any[];
```

my function,

```
test(){
  let isOnline: boolean, isWeb: boolean, isMobile: boolean;

   this.users = this.defaultUsers.map(user=>{
    isOnline = this.onlineUsers.some((onlineUser: { userid: number; })=> onlineUser.userid == user.id);      

    -- ( ! help-> I could not build the structure in my head) --

    return {...user, online: isOnline }
   });

   console.log(this.users)
  }
```

I want to get:

```
[
{id: 31, name: "A", mobile: true, web: true, online: true },
{id: 32, name: "B", mobile: true, web: false, online: true },
{id: 33, name: "C", mobile: false, web: false, online: false },
{id: 34, name: "D", mobile: false, web: false, online: false },
{id: 35, name: "E", mobile: false, web: false, online: false },
{id: 36, name: "F", mobile: false, web: false, online: false },
{id: 37, name: "G", mobile: false, web: false, online: false },
{id: 38, name: "H", mobile: false, web: false, online: false },
]
```

How can I ensure this in the most accurate and performance way? Can you help me?
I want to get the object I want using the objects in my hand.

Comment: for each online user generate a new object. Not sure what would be the callenge

Answer (score 2):

You could just retrieve users from `onlineUsers` with `.filter()` and look for the platform types:

```
  test() {
    let isOnline: boolean, isWeb: boolean, isMobile: boolean;

    this.users = this.defaultUsers.map((u) => {
      const users = this.onlineUsers.filter((onlineUser: { userid: number; platform: string; }) => onlineUser.userid == u.id);

      const isOnline = !!users.length;
      const isWeb = users.some((usr) => usr.userid === u.id && usr.platform === 'web');
      let isMobile = users.some((usr) => usr.userid === u.id && usr.platform === 'mobil');

      return { ...u, online: isOnline, web: isWeb, mobile: isMobile }
    });

    console.log(this.users)
  }
```

Live demo: [here](https://repl.it/repls/WarmheartedDisfiguredSpellchecker)

Comment: This is not a good solution. It won't check if the user has both `mobile` and `web` which is what OP is looking for

Comment: @Dino what do you mean? It produces exactly the same output as OP posted in the question

Comment: It does not. This is your output for id: 31 `{ id: 31, name: 'A', online: true, web: true, mobile: false }`. Mobile is false while it should be true.

Comment: Ooops! Did not notice that. I upvoted your answer and will fix mine. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `reduce` and `forEach`. First you iterate the `defaultUsers` array and then loop the `forEach` to decide whether the user is `online` and `isMobile` or/and `isWeb`. Performance wise you are only doing the one nested loop.

```
  this.users = this.defaultUsers.reduce((arr, user) => {
    let isOnline = false;
    let isWeb = false;
    let isMobile = false;
    this.onlineUsers.forEach((onlineUser) => {
      if (onlineUser.userid === user.id) {
        isOnline = true;
        if (onlineUser.platform === 'web') {
           isWeb = true;
        }
        if (onlineUser.platform === 'mobil') {
           isWeb = true;
        }
      }
    })
    let object = { online: isOnline, web: isWeb, mobile: isMobile }
    arr.push(Object.assign({}, user, object))
    return arr;
  }, [])
```

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpnn7x?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
test() {
  this.users = this.defaultUsers.map(user=>{
    const id = user.id;
    const name = user.name;
    const mobile = this.onlineUsers.some(onUser => 
      user.id === onUser.id && onUser.plattform === 'mobile'
    );
    const web = this.onlineUsers.some(onUser => 
      user.id === onUser.id && onUser.plattform === 'web'
    );
    const online = mobile || web;
    return {id, name, mobile, web, online};
  });   
}
```

Comment: It won't work because `mobile` and `web` will always be `true` as long as there is **any** user with platform `web` and **any** user with platform `mobil`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mx6m7e?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
this.users = this.defaultUsers.map(item => {
  let onlineUser = this.onlineUsers.filter(x => x.userid == item.id)
  return({
    ...item,
    mobile: onlineUser.some(x => x.platform == "mobil"),
    web:  onlineUser.some(x => x.platform == "web"),
    online: onlineUser.length > 0
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks short and simple but from performance side it might not be that good. Inside the map you are doing 3 more loops, while it could be done only with one.

Comment: @Dino I agree, can you verify the modified answer?

Comment: You are still looping 3 times inside the `.map`. First one is `.filter` and two other are `.some`